# Number of values stored in a function

Tags: variable-definitions, assignment

Suppose I run this:

```
f[0] = 1;
f[n_] := f[n] = 2 f[n - 1];
f[1000]
```

Now there will be 1001 values stored in `f`, and `Definition[f]` will output 1002 lines of definition. How do I get either the number of values stored or the number of lines in the definition?

Comment: `Length@DownValues@f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of lines in definition: `Length@DownValues@f`, as suggested by b3m2a1

Number of values stored: delete expressions containing the head `Pattern` from `DownValues`.

```
f[0] = 1;
f[n_] := f[n] = 2 f[n - 1];
f[m_, n_] := f[m + n];
f[1000];
Length@DownValues@f
Length@DeleteCases[DownValues@f, _?(MemberQ[#, _Pattern, ∞] &)]
(* 1003 *)
(* 1001 *)
```